# Plotly R graph in jekyll-Github personal web page

Tags: r, rubygems, jekyll, ggplotly

I'm trying to add a ggplotly graph to my GitHub Jekyll-based personal web. I tried the following:

Added the following to my site's Gemfile:

```
gem 'jekyll-include-cache'
```

Added the following to my site's config file under the *plugins*:

```
plugins:
   - jekyll-include-cache
```

let's say that this example (available on internet) is the ggplotly image I want to add to my Jekyll personal web. I used R to create it:

```
library(babynames)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(htmlwidgets)
nms <- filter(babynames, name %in% c("Sam", "Alex"))
p <- ggplot(nms) + 
  geom_line(aes(year, prop, color = sex, linetype = name))

ggp<-ggplotly(p, dynamicTicks = TRUE) %>%
  rangeslider() %>%
  layout(hovermode = "x")

saveWidget(ggp,'test.html')
```

I copied test.html to the _includes folder.

I added the following to my markdown page (about.md):

```
{% include_cached test.html %}
```

but I'm getting all the time a **liquid syntax error**.

I think I'm missing something somewhere, any ideas?

thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: **liquid syntax error**: Variable '{{if(e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t={}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/ included. I tried with a ggplotly graph but also a plotly one.

Comment: **python graph**: `import plotly.graph_objects as go
import ipywidgets

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))
fig.write_html('first_figure.html', auto_open=True)
` throw an **jekyll 3.8.5 | Error:  error parsing fragment (1)**

Comment: The same happened to me with plot_ly generated with R. I removed the aditional '{' and '}' in .html file and this problem was solved. But another one happened, I will search for more info and bring here.